# NavigationViewController stack

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am concerned about NavigationViewController stack in the sense that apple documentation says that "A navigation controller object manages the currently displayed screens using the navigation stack, which is represented by an array of view controllers." And what about another NavigationController attached to the topViewController? Is it in navigation stack? Or there are two navigation stacks? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52AVr.png) and so at the end what viewController will the top of this construction if we will call 
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
      [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

```
  guard let navController = window?.rootViewController as? 
  UINavigationController,
  let viewController = navController.topViewController else {
    return true
  }
```

Comment: The new `UINavigationController` created is added as an array element to the existing `UINavigationController` array.

Comment: so? the top view controller will be....?????

Comment: and if we add let viewController = navController.topViewController as ViewController we will 1st viewcontroller? so we can do it with navigationviewcontroller also?

Comment: `UINavigationController`s need a `UIViewController` to be added to it. Imagine it as a binder, you need to add pages to a binder to say that a binder is filled with pages. Here the pages being `UIViewController`. 

If you add a `UINavigationViewContoller` a page is added for you which is a type of `UIViewController`

Comment: So in your question, your second `UINavigationController` is just an empty stack, which is a sub-stack of your main `UINavigationViewController`. hope that helped

Comment: so then why  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  guard let navController = window?.rootViewController as? 
  UINavigationController,
  let viewController = navController.topViewController  else {
    return true
  } shows me view controller of the first navigation view controller not second?

Comment: There are two distinctive nav stack because viewController = navController.topViewController as? FilterViewController returns nil